# watermark text on textbox asp.net mvc razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, c#-3.0

I am currently working on a ASP.NET MVC3 project  and i created views to display contents , now i want to put watermark on @html.TextBoxFor() so i tried [Display(Prompt="WaterMarkText")],but its not working in IE8 and working well in Google chrome 
Please help me to put watermark ..

here is my code

```
 [Display(Prompt = "Scheme", Name = "Scheme")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]           
        public string name { get; set; }
```

view

```
                <td>
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.scheme.name)
                </td>
                <td>

                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.scheme.name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.scheme.name)
                </td>
```

Answer (score 1):

The Prompt parameter in the Display attribute just adds a "placeholder" attribute to the rendered input tag, like this:

`<input type="text" placeholder="WaterMarkText" />`

IE8 doesn't support the placeholder attribute, so you need to use javascript or CSS to achieve the same. You can do it with jQuery and this: http://www.standardista.com/html5-placeholder-attribute-script/